# ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterDataFiltered is not function?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ngtable

I am trying to do the following:

```
activate();

function activate() {
    ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterDataFiltered(function(tableParams, filteredData){
        //DO SOMETHING
    });
}
```

However, my browsers shows an error on the console:

> TypeError: ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterDataFiltered is not a function

Comment: check if you have injected table module

Comment: Yes I have, if i console out ngTableEventsChannel, I can see: 

onAfterCreated
onAfterReloadData
onDatasetChanged
onPagesChanged
publishAfterCreated
publishAfterReloadData
publishDatasetChanged
publishPagesChanged.

But not onAfterDataFiltered?

Comment: Try calling your function after 1ms , using setTimeOut

Comment: I just tried, the same result.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get all the data from all the pages of my table, I have a button on each row which is used to edit the row, so the function i call needs all the data for that table that have been filtered.